# В каких единицах измерения времени указывается query_time в slow-query логе MySQL?

Tags: mysql

В каких единицах измерения времени указывается **query_time** в *slow-query* логе MySQL?

> # Query_time: 111.187640

[В ответе на аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937160/4898850) указано, что в секундах, но ни в документации MySQL, ни по ссылке, приведённой в данном ответе, я не нашла точного указания на это.

**UPD**

И чаще всего в логе встречается время в пределах ~ 1-100, например:

> # Query_time: 1.379607
>
> # Query_time: 39.875415
>
> # Query_time: 109.606808

но есть также много записей, у которых `Query_time` слишком большое, например:

> # Query_time: 18446744073709.550781

если это время указано в секундах, то что это значит - данный запрос должен занимать более 500 лет?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть утилита [mysqldumpslow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html). В документации показан пример вывода

> shell> mysqldumpslow
>
> Reading mysql slow query log from /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld51-apple-slow.log 
>   Count: 1  Time=4.32s (4s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), root[root]@localhost
>    insert into t2 select * from t1
>
> Count: 3  Time=2.53s (7s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), root[root]@localhost
>    insert into t2 select * from t1 limit N
>
> Count: 3  Time=2.13s (6s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), root[root]@localhost
>    insert into t1 select * from t1

Все времена указаны в секундах. Думаю, что можно предположить, что и в логе оно в секундах